# Anthology dealing with collapse of galactic civilization?

Tags: story-identification

I'm looking for a short story collection I read in the mid-90's dealing with collapse of galactic civilization. It’s not the Foundation series.

One of the stories had starships that medieval level technology civilizations used to go on raids but they did not know how they worked or even that they traveled through space?  Just that the trips sometimes took months.

Comment: In The High Crusade, a short novel by Poul Anderson, medieval knights and most of a muddy 14th century English village, take over an alien ship, kill the crew, and accidentally fly to the alien homeworld where they conquer the planet using their awesome ground combat skills.  Maybe?

Comment: Faint memories of a short story or two with details like that. Sorry I can't be more definite. The one I can think of had them using oil lamps because the light bulbs had died over hundreds of years with the atomic powered spaceships. They filled the cargo holds with cavalry. The navigators learned by rote without really comprehending they were travelling FTL. They conquered the "Inner Marches" which was actually the galaxy centre. Does any of this sound familiar?

Comment: Possibly [Interstellar Empire](https://www.goodreads.com/book/show/882876.Interstellar_Empire)?

Comment: @Danny3414, that might have been [The Rebel of Valkyr](https://en.calameo.com/read/00475862802ce47455ea6) series?

Comment: ... which implies that Shawn might be looking for [Galactic Empires](http://www.isfdb.org/cgi-bin/pl.cgi?174251), perhaps.

Comment: @HarryJohnston I bet that's it ("Rebel of Valkyr" & *Galactic Empires*). you should make that an answer.

Comment: +1 for "It's not the Foundation series" out the gate!

Comment: Shawn, is [this](https://archive.org/stream/Planet_Stories_v04n08_1950-Fall#page/n3/mode/2up) the story  you remember reading? Did the book cover look like one of [these](http://www.isfdb.org/cgi-bin/titlecovers.cgi?25757) or [this](http://www.isfdb.org/cgi-bin/titlecovers.cgi?917643)?

Comment: Gosh, there are so many stores with very similar themes!

Comment: Danny3414 that sounds like the right story - it was in a hard cover collection of short stories all dealing with the decline/fall/aftermath of civilization.  I'd like to reread but that's the only story I recall 20+ years later.  It was not Rebel of Valkyr.

Comment: @ShawnWood Danny3414 described "The Rebel of Valkyr" perfectly. Horse cavalry on ancient starships lit by oil lamps, navigators with no comprehension of the distances involved, the exact terms "Inner Marches" and "Outer Marches", all there. WHAT MAKES YOU SO SURE IT'S NOT "THE REBEL OF VALKYR"? WHAT DOESN'T MATCH??

Comment: And "The Rebel of Valkyr" was in Brian Aldiss's hardcover anthology *Galactic Empires Vol. One*.

Comment: Then there's the [*Rhada*](http://www.isfdb.org/wiki/images/2/2e/BKTG04341.jpg) series by the same author (under a different name) bt that's a series of *novels* which of course did not appear in any anthologies.

Comment: I may add that parts of the story "The Road Not Taken" by Harry Turtledove are set aboard the starship of the technologically backward Roxolani whose technology is approximately 117th century level.  http://www.isfdb.org/cgi-bin/title.cgi?48609

Comment: @Danny3414 Is [this the story]() you had in mind?

Comment: @user14111 yeah, looking at the comments it was deffo the REBEL OF VALKYR that I was thinking of. However the O.P seems to think that it isn't  what he was looking for

Comment: Hmm maybe it was Rebel of Valkyr but the Anthology  is definitely not Galactic Empires as the whole anthology was about the decline of the empires.  Wish I had more to tell you than what it's not...